# Вылезает ошибки при тестировании Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, mockito

Хочу протестировать свой презентер таким способом:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public final class AuthPresenterTest {

@Mock
private
AuthView authView;

@Mock
private
AuthView$$State authViewState;

private AuthPresenter presenter;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new AuthPresenter();
    presenter.attachView(authView);
    presenter.setViewState(authViewState);
}

@Test
public void socket_shouldNotBeNull(){
    assertNotNull(presenter.socket); // Тут ошибки нет, тест проходит
}

@Test
public void socket_shouldConnectToServer(){
    presenter.test();
    verify(authViewState).showAuthFragment(); //тут вылезает ошибка
}
}
```

А вот код презентера:

```
@InjectViewState
public class AuthPresenter extends MvpPresenter<AuthView> {

@Inject
public RxSocket socket;

private AuthView view;

public AuthPresenter() {
    App.getComponent().inject(this);
    view = getViewState();
}

public void test(){ // Метод, который я тестирую
    view.showAuthFragment();
}

public void authServer(){
    socket.connect()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> {
                listenForErrors();
                view.showAuthFragment();
            }, throwable -> {
                view.showErrorFragment(null);
                throwable.printStackTrace();

            });
}

private void listenForErrors(){
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(objects -> {
                view.showError("Ошибка подключения");
                view.showErrorFragment(null);
            });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    socket.off(Socket.EVENT_ERROR);
}
}
```

И вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
authViewState.showAuthFragment();
-> at 
ru.exodus.lorehub.presenters.AuthPresenterTest.socket_shouldConnectToServe
    r(AuthPresenterTest.java:50)
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    Wanted but not invoked:
    authViewState.showAuthFragment();
   -> at 

  ru.exodus.lorehub.presenters.AuthPresenterTest.socket_shouldConnectToServe
    r(AuthPresenterTest.java:50)
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at ru.exodus.lorehub.presenters.AuthPresenterTest.socket_shouldConnectToServer(AuthPresenterTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что тест не прошёл. В методе `test()` метод `showAuthFragment()` вызывается у объекта `AuthView`. А в тесте вы мокируете и проверяете вызов у `AuthView$$State`. Нужно проверять именно у `AuthView`.

Comment: @eugeneek Это действительно помогло, но почему в примере кода
https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/blob/develop/sample-github/src/test/java/com/arellomobile/mvp/sample/github/mvp/presenters/HomePresenterTest.java
Тут пишется viewState?

Comment: Потому что там в [коде презентера](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/blob/develop/sample-github/src/main/java/com/arellomobile/mvp/sample/github/mvp/presenters/HomePresenter.java#L19) методы вызываются непосредственно у `...ViewState`. А у вас у `AuthView`, то есть у вью.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что тест не прошёл. То есть, метод, вызов которого вы ожидаете, вызыван не был.

В методе `test()` метод `showAuthFragment()` вызывается у объекта `AuthView`. А в тесте вы мокируете и проверяете вызов у `AuthView$$State`. Нужно проверять именно у `AuthView`.

Либо в презентере вызов методов вью должен выглядеть примерно так `getViewState().showAuthFragment();`. Moxy проксирует вызовы к `View` через `ViewState`.